# Horizontal scrollbar to certain columns

Tags: html

In my table there are certain columns..i want to give horizontal scrollbar to last 5 columns as a whole..that means there will be only one scroll bar for 5 columns.. I want functionality that if no. of column increases scroll bar should appear.
there are total 9 columns in table..
How to do it? please help.

Comment: use css property overflow-x:scroll

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `overflow-x: scroll;` in your css.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/S8jLA/

If you want your cells to keep a fixed size even if the content is too big, and to have a scrollbar if this content needs it, it's a little more complex.
Here's a solution using  divs in the cells :

HTML :

```
<table border=2 >
<tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td><div class=scr>AAA</div></td>
    <td><div class=scr>AAABAAAAACAAAA</div></td>
</tr>
```

CSS :

```
td {
    width:80px;
}
div.scr {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:80px;
    overflow-x: auto;    
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/sQZD7/

Comment: I want to give scroll bar to last 5 columns as whole..not each individual column..there should be only one scroll bar for 5 column..and if no. of colums increases then scroll will be activated..

Comment: So why not put a table in the last div as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/vJGRX/) ?

Comment: Dear dystroy , I dont have only one row in my table.. Will this work for multiple rows?

Comment: This will work but you'll have to fix the height of the rows to ensure the same height in the whole table. I suggest you have a look at [existing plugins](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugins/tables/) to ensure some don't do what you need.